# iBooks style of Search

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, asynchronous, nsoperation

I'd like to perform  multiple search operations at the same time and update UITableView as results appear, similar to the iBooks search.

The hard part is to make the table view refresh the display while search is going on.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should search in separate thread to UI remains responsive. When search has finished and dataSource of UITableView updated you should call:

```
[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: This what I exactly made. UI is responsive but the TableView is updated once with all rows. What I need is to let the user see the rows appear one after another while search is progressing. I think the scenario is to use BeginUpdates and EndUpdates and insert rows manually. It would be great if someone had wrote a tutorial for this.